# PHP Logic Not What is Expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am adding conditional validation to my Laravel 5.1 site. The actual validation is working but my logic never seems to work as expected.

I have on my form three check boxes, each on should provide a value of `true` when checked. This works with no issue.

The issue is in my validation, as seen in the code below. The test always returns `false` no matter if the boxes are checked or not. I have the code validator below.

```
$validator->sometimes('email', 'required|email|max:255|unique:members,email', function($request) {
            return $request->input('email_newsletter') === 'true';
        });
```

**Update:**
Below is the full output of `var_dump($request->input('email_newsletter'));` with the email checkbox checked:

```
    object(Illuminate\Support\Fluent)#205 (1) { ["attributes":protected]=> array(8) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "arWeDoYSBUPDh6TnD2CI7xPbg5xfG4lyiCFjh1ZF" ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["phone"]=> string(0) "" ["email_newsletter"]=> string(4) "true" ["text_message"]=> string(5) "false" ["call_message"]=> string(5) "false" ["input"]=> string(16) "email_newsletter" } }
```

Comment: Could the issue be that when checkboxes are not checked they are not even sent to the php script by the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, I have a hidden value for false before the check boxs. As well I have done a dd on the variable and got the correct value.

Comment: try removing the quotes from 'true' in this line: `return $request->input('email_newsletter') === true;`...not sure if it will work or not, but worth a shot.

Comment: @RichardTheobald I tried that earlier. When I do this it does the same, except it is always true.

Comment: @RichardTheobald I read your comment wrong. When rewritting that line the way you did it still does not work, except it still returns false. On my last comment I had it wrote as `return $request->input('email_newsletter');`.

Comment: That makes it sound to me like `$request->input('email_newsletter')` is not returning literally `'true' or true`, but some value that is truthy. A possible fix would be to use double equal signs instead of triple. Alternatively, investigate what, exactly, `$request->input('email_newsletter')` is giving you by doing `var_dump($request->input('email_newsletter');`.

Comment: @RichardTheobald Using only two equal signs is making everything true consonantly.Using var_dump I see that it is posting a string, true. I will update my question with the full result of the var_dump.

Comment: Ah, see, the var_dump shows that $request->input('email_newsletter") returns an object. That's your problem. Unfortunately, the "attributes" variable is protected, so you're not going to be able to get at it unless there's some sort of "get" function to the class. Because what you actually need is `$request->input('email_newsletter')->attributes["email_newsletter"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument passed to the `Closure` for the validation is an `Illuminate\Support\Fluent` object that contains the input, it is not the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object. You just access the information directly as attributes, without calling any method:

```
$validator->sometimes('email', 'required|email|max:255|unique:members,email', function($input) {
    return $input->email_newsletter === 'true';
});
```

Before, when you use the statement `$request->input('email_newsletter')`, all this does is actually set the `input` attribute on the object to `'email_newsletter'`, and then returns the `Fluent` object, which is then used in your comparison. You can see this in the dump that you added, the last attribute in the array is `["input"]=> string(16) "email_newsletter"`.

You can read up in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules). The red box at the end of the section notes the object passed into the closure.